# How to fix error not found plugin maven-surefire-plugin >= 2.20 on IntelliJ

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I tried to migrate to java 11. But when I change the version of plugin maven-surefire-plugin to 2.22.2 that supports java 11, maven or IntelliJ can not find it:

[image]

I tried with other versions >= 2.20, but had same error. 
I tried to fix it:

1. Firstly, invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ, then reimport maven. But still error.
2. I deleted all directories in ~/.m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins, and then reimport maven. But maven imported plugin maven-surefire-plugin version 2.19.1 automatically, not imported version 2.22.2 (:

[image]

- Update: I installed maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.2 successfully by maven command line: **mvn install**. It downloaded the plugin but IntelliJ still has the error. I tried to invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ, it worked.

Thanks @Andrey for the great suggestion!

Comment: The message seemed to be saying that your download does not work ..

Comment: Does Maven command line build work?

Comment: Thank @Andrey! I installed by maven, and then invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ. The plugin worked.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed this issue, I do:

- I installed maven-surefire-plugin version 2.22.2 successfully by
  maven command line: mvn install. It downloaded the plugin but
  IntelliJ still has the error.
- And then I tried to invalidate caches and restart IntelliJ, it
  worked.

Thanks @Andrey for the great suggestion!

Answer (score 2):

my solution was to add the dependency, but to stay organized, I added it as test scope

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.22.2</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add dependency org.apache.maven.plugins and it works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).